# gpu utilization question( nvidia-smi prints that I am using gpu but task manager shows I am not using gpu. I am using Windows subsystem for linux)

Tags: tensorflow

[Nvidia-smi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etUlT.png)

[GPU utilisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIDFv.png)

I was trying to train LLaMa model. nvidia-smi prints that I am using gpu but task manager shows I am not using gpu. I am using Windows subsystem for linux). When I test the gpu availability with python even then it returen true but task manager shows zero utilisation for GPU